# Dynamic width DIV next to a static width DIV

Tags: asp.net, html, css

Its in all in the title.

I'm trying to get a div on the left of the page to a static width 170px; this works fine.

What I'm having issues with is getting a div next to it, that scales to fit the remaining width.

Is there a simple approach I can use here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the right-hand div, just set a margin:

```
style="margin-left: 170px;"
```

Here's an example page, works here:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Jquery Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function()  {
        var right = $("#right");
        $("#toggle").click(function() {
          $("#left").animate({"width": "toggle"}, {
            duration: 250,
            step: function() {
                right.css("margin-left", $(this).width());
            }
          }, function() { right.css("margin-left", $("#left").width()); });             
        });
      });
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
      #left { width: 170px; float: left; border: solid 1px red; }
      #right { margin-left: 170px; border: solid 1px green; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="left">Test</div>
    <div id="right">Test Right</div>
    <input id="toggle" value="Open/Close" type="button" />    
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what if you want to put content there?

Comment: @Robert Greiner: There is already content...the left-hand div

Comment: @Nate Bross: I added an example page, they combine to form 100% width, no horizontal scrolling...is this not what you're after?

Comment: Now, assume that I want to expand and collapse the div on the left, I would simply adjust it's "width" property and the "margin-left" of the rght div at te same time via my JS "Collapse" method?

Comment: @Nate Bross: I added to the example page showing how to toggle the thing open/closed with a button.  Let me know if this isn't what you're after.  Using jQuery's step callback you can ensure the divs are in sync while they animate.

Comment: Wow thanks. Above and beyond. I was simply asking if that was the right approach. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can define your css classes like this:

```
#left-div {
    margin-left: 0px;
    width: 170px;
    float: left;
}
#right-div {
    margin-left: 170px;
    margin-right: 0px;
}
```

This will keep the left margin of the right div next to the left div, and the right margin at the right edge of the window.

Comment: Will this allow me to put a table inside and set its width to 100% and fill all the space of #right-div?

Comment: Yes, you will be able to put a 100% width table. Set the id of the divs to "left-div" and "right-div" respectively.